# Using ansible to launch nginx web server: localhost:8080 not responding

Tags: nginx, vagrant, ansible, localhost, yaml

I am experimenting with Ansible by reading the great *Ansible Up and Running* book by  Lorin Hochstein.

On a Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Ansible, I am trying now to run the *web-tls* playbook.

As example, I created a *web-notls.yml* file and I did put in the *playbook* directory:

```
    - name: Configure webserver with nginx
hosts: webservers
sudo: True
tasks:
- name: install nginx
apt: name=nginx update_cache=yes
- name: copy nginx config file
copy: src=files/nginx.conf dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
- name: enable configuration
file: >
dest=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
src=/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
state=link
- name: copy index.html
template: src=templates/index.html.j2 dest=/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
mode=0644
- name: restart nginx
service: name=nginx state=restarted
```

I also specified a *nginx.conf*file and I did put it in *playbooks/files/nginx.conf* directory:

```
   server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;
server_name localhost;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

I also created hosts file to access the Vagrant machine easily and a web custom homepage to see a message after accessing the web page.

I modified the *Vagrantfile* to contain this code:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
end
```

After this change, the port 8080 on my local machine should be forwarded t othe port 80 of the Vagrant machine, and the port 8443 on my local machine should be forwarded to ort 443 on the vagrant machine:
[8080 Port forwarding Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qbrY.png)
When trying to run the playbook by:

```
$ ansible-playbook web-notls.yml
```

the ouput is:

```
luigi@luigi-H87-HD3:~/playbooks$ ansible-playbook web-notls.yml 
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: [defaults]hostfile option, The key is misleading as it can also be a list of 
hosts, a directory or a list of paths , use [defaults] inventory=/path/to/file|dir instead. This 
feature will be removed in version 2.8. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Instead of sudo/sudo_user, use become/become_user and make sure become_method
 is 'sudo' (default). This feature will be removed in version 2.6. Deprecation warnings can be 
disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

PLAY [Configure webserver with nginx] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [install nginx] ********************************************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [copy nginx config file] ***********************************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [enable configuration] *************************************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [copy index.html] ******************************************************************************
ok: [testserver]

TASK [restart nginx] ********************************************************************************
changed: [testserver]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************
testserver                 : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

It seems like no errors so far. I am now trying to open *localhost:8080* address by browser on my local machine (I also tried to do a vagrant ssh and try curl localhost:8080 with no success) but I receive no results. What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance, there were no errors from the anisble output, so I think that the script did it's job. The error seems to be that you should be looking at **localhost:80** not *localhost:8080*.

Comment: Hi Tomslva, thanks for answer. I edited my original post with details on how I am trying to do the port forwarding. Do you have any additonal suggestions on what to investigate ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1.) First check that nginx is actually running (sudo service nginx status) or  "sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 80 (to see that nginx is on that port) 2.) What output do you get from curl localhost:8080 in the vagrant machine? 3.) Also, check that there is an nginx .conf file in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ directory.

Comment: Commands results:
1
`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo service nginx status
 * nginx is running`
2
`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl localhost:80
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Welcome to ansible</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>nginx, configured by Ansible</h1>
 <p>If you can see this, Ansible successfully installed nginx.</p>
 
 <p>Ansible managed</p>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: 3
in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ I find the "default" file:
`server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}`

Comment: Ok, so the server in running successfully in vagrant and you can curl the page, the problem seems to be in port forwarding section, somethings is not corrextly configured in the vagrant file or there is the possibility that on your host computer there is something already running on port 8080

Comment: From the _vagrant reload_ command it seems like port forwarding is not being applied correctly:

[...]
`==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...`
[...]
I would expect a `default: 80 => 8080` (adapter 1) message here

Comment: ok, that seems like a good clue, but for snippets (examples) like the one you were looking in the book, I think a good alternative would be to use docker, it's faster and doesn't give you an overhead as an VM solution like vagrant (and the configuration is easier)... but If you would like to stick to vagrant, then check its configuration file, I have a hunch that the problem you are facing is there...

Comment: Found. When modifying my _Vagrantfile_ I didn't realize this code: `VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
end` was preceded by `VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"` at the first few rows of the file. I suppose this caused the second part of the code to not being run effectively. I removed the first redundant rows and it then worked flawlessly. I can now see the welcome page via browser.